# How can I match the value of a slider to an angularjs variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-3rd-party

What I want is to match: the maximum and minimum value of the slide to the variable to filter filterModelMin.precio.

I did it this way but it throws me an error.

```
<rzslider rz-slider-model="slider.minValue"
          rz-slider-high="slider.maxValue"
          rz-slider-options="slider.options"></rzslider>
              </div>
              <input   ng-model="filterModelMin.precio =slider.minValue">
               <input   ng-model="filterModelMax.precio= slider.maxValue">

  <a flex ng-repeat="apartament in apartaments | dynamicFilter:Filters:this | filter:byRange('precio', filterModelMin.precio, filterModelMax.precio)| filter:{departamento:ordenSeleccionado, municipio: ordenSeleccionadomuni}"
          ng-href="{{ post.url }}">
```

Comment: Since the `ng-model` expressions are illegal, it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Your slider min and text min should both use this model:  `filterModelMin.precio`.  Your slider max and text max should both use this model:  `filterModelMax.precio`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `ng-model` expressions are illegal, it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Possibly you want:

```
̵<̵i̵n̵p̵u̵t̵ ̵n̵g̵-̵m̵o̵d̵e̵l̵=̵"̵f̵i̵l̵t̵e̵r̵M̵o̵d̵e̵l̵M̵i̵n̵.̵p̵r̵e̵c̵i̵o̵ ̵=̵s̵l̵i̵d̵e̵r̵.̵m̵i̵n̵V̵a̵l̵u̵e̵"̵>̵
̶<̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶ ̶n̶g̶-̶m̶o̶d̶e̶l̶=̶"̶f̶i̶l̶t̶e̶r̶M̶o̶d̶e̶l̶M̶a̶x̶.̶p̶r̶e̶c̶i̶o̶=̶ ̶s̶l̶i̶d̶e̶r̶.̶m̶a̶x̶V̶a̶l̶u̶e̶"̶>̶

<div>{{ filterModelMin.precio=slider.minValue }}</div>
<div>{{ filterModelMax.precio=slider.maxValue }}</div>
```